# Object pool and flash

Tags: actionscript-3, object-pooling

When is it a good idea to use an object pool in Flash? For example, is it a good/bad idea with bitmaps, MovieClips (with timeline animations inside of them), video, fonts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Michael](http://lab.polygonal.de/2008/06/18/using-object-pools/) wrote an interesting article about object pools.